# verified docker's container with php?

Tags: php, docker, containers

I have a server with some docker container that are launch to host some game party.

I would like to list my docker's containers and see if my servers are up or down.
But I don't know how to do it.
My project is to make IHM list docker's containers and see if the containers are up or down. I would like to do it in PHP.

I've tried to list a basic file lister function in PHP but it didn't work. I tried with $_SERVER variable.

Do you know if it's possible and how I can do it?

Thank you.

Comment: I use https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php to list/start/stop and most other things with Docker containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to check containers up/down:**

```
docker ps -a
```

It shows you exited and running containers. If you want also check if your server programs are working well, `docker ps -a` is also useful for that if your programs have been launched as ENTRYPOINTS.
Otherwise, if you want to check if other program that is not the entrypoint is up/down, see next section:

**If you want to check programs working well inside a started container:**
Is possible that your container is up but is not working well because you want to check other programs. 
For this case, you can define a HEALTHCHECK: [docker documentation healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck)

At this point, you can define a PHP program which checks healthy and it's running inside container and you could see from outside this PHP program output.

In other words, you can define in your docker:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD <your PHP check program> || exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We like to have a "health" url in each of our services.

e.g. in Laravel we define our web routes like that:

```
Route::any('health', function() {
    try {
        foreach (['default', 'secondDbConnection', 'thirdDbConnection'] as $dbConnection) {
            DB::connection($dbConnection)->getPdo();
        }
        return response('OK', 200);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
});

Route::any('ping', function() {
    return response('pong', 200);
});
```

That way you can check that a service including e.g. its db is healthy.

On your health dashboard you can then check all /health urls